# Is it possible/advisable to try and update libc6 without rebooting the machine?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, libc6

I want to update the `libc6` package on a running production server without incurring downtime.

AFAIK pretty much everything on the system depends on `libc6` either directly or indirectly:

```
$ sudo apt-cache rdepends libc6 | wc -l
21026
```

It would be possible to go through and one-by-one restart/reload services that depend on it, but there's a chance that I'd miss one or more.

Obviously a reboot would get 100% of the necessary services, but I'd like to hear if anyone has a standard solution for either accomplishing this in a quick, repeatable way, or at least a way to make it easier.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `checkrestart` utility from `debian-goodies` package and restart only listed services

Comment: Thanks, `checkrestart` looks really useful. Unfortunately the list of services that it gives me is almost every service - seems like I might have to figure out the best way to allow for a reboot